# Design nightmare with PHP

Tags: php, class, design-patterns

I've been trying for a long time now to find a correct design using PHP to achieve what I want, but everything I've tried failed and I'm guessing it's probably because I'm not looking from the right angle, so I wish some of you can enlighten me and give me some good advice!

The design might seem a little weird at first, but I assure you it's not because I like to make things complicated. For the sake of simplicity I'm only giving the minimal structure of my problem and not the actual code. It starts with these:

```
<?php

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Mother_A
{
    const _override_1 = 'default';
    protected static $_override_2 = array();

    public static function method_a()
    {
        $c = get_called_class();
        // Uses $c::_override_1 and $c::$_override_2
    }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Mother_B extends Mother_A
{
    public function method_b()
    {
        // Uses self::method_a()
    }
}
```

Class `Mother_A` defines a static method that uses constants and statics to be overridden by children. This allows to define a generic method (equivalent of a "template" method) in the derived class `Mother_B`. Neither `Mother_A` or `Mother_B` are intended to be instanciated, but `Mother_B` should not be abstract. This exploits Late Static Binding, which I find very useful btw.

Now comes my problem. I want to define two classes, in n distinct 'situations' (situation 1, situation 2, etc):

```
<?php 

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Child_A_Situation_k extends Mother_A
{
    // Uses method_a
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Child_B_Situation_k extends Mother_B
{
    // Uses method_a and method_b
}
```

Of course I'm not actually giving these stupid names; both classes have different names in each situation, but both follow the same derivation pattern from `Mother_A` and `Mother_B`. However, in each individual case ('situation'), both classes need the *exact same* constants/static override, and I don't know how to do that without duplicating the override manually in both classes.

---

I tried many things, but the closest I got was to implement an interface `Interface_Situation_k` that defined constants and statics for the situation k, and make both children implement this interface. Of course, you can't define statics in an interface, so it failed, but you get the idea. I would have traded the interface for a class, but then there's no multiple inheritance in PHP, so it's not valid either. :/ I'm really stuck, and I can't wait to read a possible solution! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would it be fair to say that your entire question could be summarised as "How do I emulate multiple-inheritance in PHP?"?

Comment: Man this is a nightmare indeed. Why don't you pick up some framework to make things easier?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Not really, multiple inheritance could be a solution if it was possible, but I don't want to restrict all the possible solutions to this category.. Plus I don't know if "static/constant attributes inheritance" would really qualify as a multiple inheritance case. :/

Comment: @MightyPork I'm using a framework already, but explaining what's behind would be longer and irrelevant :)

Comment: `because I like to make things complicated` Why? I like solving complicated problems in a simple way, not creating complicated problems.

Comment: here is a good description on a workaround for multiple inheritance in php: http://www.serversidemagazine.com/php/how-to-inherit-from-multiple-objects-workaround/ That might work for you, if not, i still think reflection is the way to go here

Comment: @x4rf41 I actually read that article a few days ago, and I don't think it's a good way because I don't want these 'overridden variables' to be instance attributes. I want them to be static (or constant), because they shouldn't change at all for a given situation, and I can potentially get a lot of instances of `Child_A_Situation_k` which would take up a lot of memory for nothing.

Comment: still possible with reflection, but i dont really understand exactly what you are trying to achieve, if you would show a working example, and show the lines that you had to duplicate but didnt want to (thats the problem isnt it?), i could help you more specifically

Comment: @x4rf41 Just add `const _override_1 = 'something_k';` and `protected static _override_2 = array('else_k');` to both children, and you get a working example with the duplicated lines.

Comment: It sounds like you may be overusing inheritance.  Should you really be able to use a `Child_B_Situation_K` in every case where you'd use a `Mother_A`?  If not, perhaps you should consider *owning* an instance of `Mother_A` rather than trying to *be* one.

Comment: Add to that, PHP objects are duck-typed by default.  You could have a class that acts like some other.  If you want the functionality to be shared, but don't truly need to have the two related by inheritance, traits may help.

Comment: @cHao I'm interested by the traits, and by the idea of faking inheritance; could you explain these further in an answer?

Comment: @cHao Actually, your previous comment about owning a `Mother_A` instance goes in the same category as x4rf41's comment; my constants/static variables would become instance variables of `Mother_B` and of `Child_A_Situation_k`, no?

Comment: Not quite.  They'd still be static members of their respective classes.  You could have your own variables there, but LSB wouldn't work with them.  If you need LSB, then you'd need to do something else.  Exactly what, though, depends on the actual situation.  Your stripped-down example begs the question by pre-supposing that inheritance is the best or only way to relate these classes.

Comment: Why the downvote? To whoever did this; read the answer of x4rf41 below, and see if you still think its a useless question, or that it's not well formulated, then post a comment to explain why please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the best i can do, i don't think there is a way to do it with less code.
Look at the comments inside the code for more info.

Fully working code:

```
<?php

class Mother_A
{
    // you're using '_override_1' as a variable, so its obviously not a constant
    // also i made it public for the setSituation function, 
    // you could keep it protected and use reflections to set it
    // but i dont really see a reason for that. 
    // if you want that, look up how to set private/protected variables
    public static $_override_1 = 'default'; 
    public static $_override_2 = array();

    public static function method_a()
    {
        $c = get_called_class();
        var_dump($c::$_override_1);
        var_dump($c::$_override_2);
        // Uses $c::_override_1 and $c::$_override_2
    }

    public static function setSituation($className)
    {
        $c = get_called_class();
        // iterate through the static properties of $className and $c 
        // and when the you find properties with the same name, set them
        $rBase = new ReflectionClass($c);
        $rSituation = new ReflectionClass($className);
        $staBase = $rBase->getStaticProperties();
        $staSituation = $rSituation->getStaticProperties();
        foreach($staSituation as $name => $value)
        {
            if(isset($staBase[$name])) $c::$$name = $value;
        }
    }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Mother_B extends Mother_A
{
    public function method_b()
    {
        self::method_a();
    }
}

class Situation_k
{
    public static $_override_1 = 'k';
    public static $_override_2 = array('k','k');
}

class Child_A_Situation_k extends Mother_A { }
Child_A_Situation_k::setSituation('Situation_k'); 
// This is not as short as writing 'extends Mother_A, Situation_k'
// but i think you wont get it shorter

class Child_B_Situation_k extends Mother_B { }
Child_B_Situation_k::setSituation('Situation_k');

echo '<pre>';
Child_A_Situation_k::method_a();
echo "\n";
Child_B_Situation_k::method_a();
echo "\n";
Child_B_Situation_k::method_b();
echo "\n";
echo '</pre>';
?>
```